# Proof reading of one college-Algebra-polynomial-thereom.

Tags: polynomials

Welcome to edit my post to revise any mistakes, especially English, thanks.

Theorem 11: If an nozero integer polynomial $f(x)$ can be factored as a product of two rational polynomials and less degree, then it can be factored as a product of two integer polynomials and less degree.

Suppose integer polynomial $f (x)$ has a factorization.
$f(x)=g(x) h(x)$, where $f (x)$, $g (x)$ are all rational polynomials,and

$\partial (g (x)) < \partial (f (x))$
$\partial (h (x)) < \partial (f (x))$

Let $f (x) = a f_1 (x)$, $g (x) = r g_1 (x)$, $h (x) = s h_1 (x)$, 
Here $f_1(x)$, $g_1 (x)$ are all primitive polynomials, where a is an integer, r and s are all rational numbers.

Hence $af_1(x)=r s g_1(x)h_1(x)$.

From Thereom 10(Gaussian Lemma: product of two primitive polynomials is also a primitive polynomial), $g_1(x)h_1(x)$ is primitive polynomial, therefore
$r s=\pm a$, This is saying that, $r s$ is an integer. 
Hence, we have $f(x)=\left(r s g_1(x)\right)h_1(x)$. 
Here $r\text{  }s g_1(x)$ and $h_1(x)$ are all integer polynomials and with degree less than that of $f(x)$

Comment: Check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial)

Comment: The English is ok: there are a few errors (e.g. it should be "*are* such questions welcome?" and you've spelled Theorem and nonzero wrongly) but it is good enough that we can understand you clearly.

Comment: How precisely do you deduce that $\, rs = \pm a\,$? Do your prior theorems handle rational (vs. integral) content?

Comment: @Key Ideas Theorem 10 is Gauss Lemma, Two primitive polynomials' product is also an primitive polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: @mt_ thanks, I should be more confident in English with your encouragement. Which is right? integer polynomial or integral polynomial

Comment: @HyperGroups integer polynomial is best, you could also say "polynomial over the integers" or "polynomial with integer coefficients"

Comment: @mt_ OK, I ask this because I think integer is an noun and rational `in rational polynomial` is an adjective. They seems different in PartOfSpeech , and integral would be conflicted with that in calculus.